# Do rendered-to-textures need to be bound when being drawn to?

Tags: opengl, textures, multiple-render-targets

In OpenGL, if I'm rendering to a texture using a framebuffer, do I have to have that texture bound while I'm rendering to it? In code:

```
glBindTexture(...);
glTexImage2D(...);

glBindFramebuffer(...);
glFrameBufferTexture2D(...);

//START DRAWING HERE: does the texture I'm rendering to need to be bound here?
```

Comment: You can't have the texture bound if you want to use some other texture while drawing to your framebuffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

When you bind textures to a `GL_FRAMEBUFFER` object (FBO), those textures get associated with it. Later, when you bind the FBO, the associated textures get bound as well.

An example:

```
// a framebuffer with a color texture and a depth texture

m_TexWidth = 1024;
m_TexHeight = 1024;

m_TextureTotal = 2;
m_Texture = new GLuint[m_TextureTotal];
glGenTextures(m_TextureTotal, m_Texture);

glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_Target);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_Target);

// color

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture[0]);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, m_TexWidth, m_TexHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture[0], 0);

// depth

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture[1]);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, m_TexWidth, m_TexHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_Texture[1], 0);

GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    LOG_FATAL("Could not validate framebuffer");
}
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Now, if you want to use that framebuffer so you can render to it:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_Target);
```

And back to the backbuffer:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

**EDIT:** Earlier I claimed that textures are created per FBO. That is wrong, all textures are always created global in OpenGL. The difference is that these textures are now *associated* with the FBO.

Comment: You are right. I got a bit confused. Fixed it to make more sense.

Comment: "the associated textures get bound as well." No, they don't. "Bind" always refers to associating an object with the OpenGL context. AKA, `glBindTexture`. Binding an FBO does not *bind* the textures attached to it. The textures are still attached, and thus rendering to the FBO means rendering to those textures.

Comment: Thanks, these answers and comments were exactly what I was looking for. It is particularly helpful that binding the FBO does not bind the textures. Does that mean if I have a rendered-to texture that I bound to GL_TEXTURE0 I can still use GL_TEXTURE0 for drawing while the framebuffer is bound?

Answer (score 5):

No, the texture doesn't need to be bound.